# User is getting a RESOLVER.RST.AuthRequired e-mail bounce from a customer

Tags: exchange-2010, email-bounces

I've been looking all over the Internet for a solution to this issue but it seems none of the solutions fit my symptoms.  I am unable to get any e-mail to a customer.  His server keeps responding with this:

```
< #5.7.1 smtp;550 5.7.1 RESOLVER.RST.AuthRequired; authentication required>.
```

and this:

> Your message wasn't delivered due to a permission or security issue.
>   It may have been rejected by a moderator, the address may only accept
>   e-mail from certain senders, or another restriction may be preventing
>   delivery.

I also noticed later in the email this:

```
Authentication-Results: symauth.service.identifier
Received: from xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxx (xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxx [yy.yyy.yyy.yyy])   
(using TLS with cipher AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)) (Client did not present a certificate)
```

I'm running an off internet Exchange 2010 server.  Exchange is forwarding email through a Sendmail 8.14 server connected to the internet.  Could this be a misconfiguration at my recipient's mail server or could it be on my end??  We're not using distributions lists.  My user is having no problems sending or receiving mail from anyone else, including receiving from this recipient.  The "Require that all senders are authenticated" is NOT checked.  I'm at my witts end here.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  After doing some more research I noticed this little entry in my sendmail logs.

> Oct  2 10:48:50 stc-mailrelay sendmail[28195]: ruleset=check_relay,
>   arg1=[74.117.209.97], arg2=127.0.0.2, relay=edely.net [74.117.209.97]
>   (may be forged), reject=550 5.7.1 Mail from 74.117.209.97 refused -
>   see http:/www.spamhaus.org/query/bl?ip=74.117.209.97

That IP is not owned by myself nor the recipient.  I am assuming it is a relay somewhere between us and the recipient?  Also, I've just learned that it is only one user at the recipient company who is bouncing all user's email from mine.  Other users at the recipient company are able to receive email from us.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a configuration issue or setting on the destination mail server which requires inbound sessions to be authenticated.

Can the customer receive mail from other hosts on that particular address?

Is the address you are sending to actually a distribution list on the destination mail server?

Has the destination mail server recently implemented an anti-spam solution (specifically Symantec Messaging Gateway as this error suggests)?

Comment: All users except for this specific recipient can receive mail with no issues from any of my users.  But if anyone here tries to send mail to that specific recipient it gets bounced.  Nothing on my end has installed an anti-spam gateway from Symantic.  My gateway anti-spam is Sonicwall and not enabled.

Comment: Based on the fact that it's only this recipient having the problem, I suspect your client has an incorrectly-configured Symantec Messaging Gateway system in this instance. Can you send to them from a hotmail or gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seem to be at your end.

```
Your message wasn't delivered due to a permission or security issue. It may have been         rejected by a moderator, the address may only accept e-mail from certain senders, or another   restriction may be preventing delivery. 'symauth.service.identifier' It seems to be content filter policy by Symantec Messaging Gateway which might be refusing your message.
```

1. This clearly states that the problem with message delivery is
   getting refused by the destination mail server. You may try to ask
   the destination server admin to check the logs and why it is
   refusing to accept your email.
2. You can try to check email headers to see for additional information
   e.g, from which destination it is bouncing from, from an ISP or from
   the destination server
3. You can try send an email using a public email service to check if
   it is able to reach to the destination.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Notice the Spamhaus entry in my latest edit.  Could it be that a relay in between myself and the recipient is being rejected by only that recipient, not any other users from the same company?

Comment: As it seems the destination mail server is using Symantec enterprise messaging gateway and Spamhaus is a public RBL. It might be symantec enterprise messaging gateway 's plociy which is using that RBL and refusing your message to accept for delivery.

Comment: I have already mentioned it in my answer after editing but I guess the answer didn't get updated.

Comment: So, do I have any recourse?  Should I try to get hold of the owner of the IP (74.117.209.97) since that's the one that is listed at Spamhaus?

Comment: Usually Spamhaus deletes the IP address after 24 hours. In that case you don't need to do anything. If this is an IP of a mail server its better to use SPF and it should be listed in whitelist of Content filtering.